# MySQL not properly ordering results

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a database for an application I am developing for and organization . I am having problem with one of my queries and I can't figure out why. I will discus the relevant tables.  First table holds all of the information about various groups in this organization. Second hold members of the organization.  Third holds what groups members can belong to. Last one hold information about file upload of members.  Purpose of this query is to return how many files were uploaded by members organized by group month and year.

This is the query

```
SELECT 
COUNT(archive.member_id) AS total,
EXTRACT(year FROM archive.submit_date) AS arc_year,
DATE_FORMAT(archive.submit_date, '%M') AS arc_month,
groups.weekday_id,
groups.group_name
FROM group_member_list
INNER JOIN groups ON group_member_list.group_id = groups.group_id
INNER JOIN archive ON group_member_list.member_id = archive.member_id
GROUP BY arc_year, arc_month, groups.group_name
ORDER BY archive.submit_date DESC ,groups.weekday_id ASC
```

this is the output from my test data

```
total   arc_year   arc_month weekday_id   group_name
 3       2016       April      4          Wednesday group
 4       2016       April      7          Saturday group
 4       2016       April      1          Sunday group
 3       2016       March      1          Sunday group
 3       2016       March      4          Wednesday group
 4       2016       March      7          Saturday group
 3       2016       February   1          Sunday group
 3       2016       February   4          Wednesday group
 4       2016       February   7          Saturday group
 3       2016       January    1          Sunday group
 3       2016       January    4          Wednesday group
 4       2016       January    7          Saturday group
 3       2015       December   1          Sunday group
 3       2015       December   4          Wednesday group
 4       2015       December   7          Saturday group
```

Everything works except the first 3 result are not ordered everything else is. I can't figure out why.

Comment: should not groups.weekday_id be in the GROUP BY part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL *is* ordering the results properly, according the expressions in the ORDER BY clause.

It's just not the order you *expect*. The fact that you observe some rows ordered in the expected order is coincidental.

The problem is in an expression in the ORDER BY clause. To understand this behavior, to see why MySQL is ordering rows the way it does, we can add the columns/expressions in the ORDER BY clause to the SELECT list of the query.

```
SELECT ... 
     , archive.submit_date

 GROUP BY arc_year, arc_month, groups.group_name
 ORDER BY archive.submit_date DESC, groups.weekday_id ASC
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you look at the values of `submit_date` that are returned, you will see that MySQL *is* honoring the ORDER BY specification:

```
arc_year arc_month submit_date weekday_id group_name
-------- --------- ----------- ---------- --------------- 
2016     April     2016-04-06   4          Wednesday group
2016     April     2016-04-09   7          Saturday group
2016     April     2016-04-10   1          Sunday group
```

What you may not expect is those particular values for submit_date.

The values returned for `submit_date` are *indeterminate*. The `submit_date` column in the resultset will be assigned a value from a row in the group. But it's *any* value. It's not guaranteed to be the lowest value, the last value, the first value or the highest value.

The ORDER BY operation is performed *after* the GROUP BY operation. An *indeterminate* value is returned for `submit_date`, and then the rows are sorted using the values returned for `submit_date`.

(NOTE: Other SQL databases would throw an error with this query. The error has to do with referencing a "non-aggregate expression" in the ORDER BY clause (or SELECT list) when the expression doesn't *also* appear in the GROUP BY clause. A default installation of MySQL enables a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY which allows this query to execute.  We can get MySQL to more closely adhere to the SQL standard (and return an error for this query) by including "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" in the sql_mode for the session.)

The fix is change the query to change the ORDER BY to specify a different expression. For example:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(archive.submit_date,'%Y%m') DESC, groups.weekday_id ASC
```

wiil return something like this:

```
arc_year arc_month yyyymm      weekday_id group_name
-------- --------- ----------- ---------- --------------- 
2016     April     201604      1          Sunday group 
2016     April     201604      4          Wednesday group
2016     April     201604      7          Saturday group
```

(It's not necessary to include expressions in the ORDER BY in the SELECT list. We do it here just so we can "see" what's happening.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's why:
It sorts correctly by weekday.
Problem is, the weekdays got probably "grouped" by groups.group_name and only one (first) weekday is shown.

Comment: Or more precisely, the weekday value is from a *indeterminate* row. The value is from some row in the "group", but it can be from *any* row in the group. It isn't necessarily the highest value, the lowest value, the value from the first row, or the last row. If OP added the column to the SELECT list, it would become obvious why the rows are sorted the way that they are. One fix is to remove from the ORDER BY clause columns/expressions which are not in the GROUP BY, and instead use columns/expressions that are either in the GROUP BY or dependent on columns/expressions in the GROUP BY.

Comment: The "fix" is to change to  **`ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(archive.submit_date,'%Y%m') DESC, groups.weekday_id ASC`**

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by year and month only, but sorting by the exact date first, then by weekday. So if there's a case where an earlier weekday does not have data until the second (or later) week of the month - e.g. Sunday April 3 has no data, but Wed April 6 does - then the latter will show up first.

Suggestion: do you care about sorting by date? If not (since you don't output it anyway) why not remove it? If yes for some reason, maybe move it down in sort priority. Anyway, that's all I can tell without having the data.